# make: /bin/javac: Command not found

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, javac

I am trying to follow the setup of this application: https://github.com/michaelmior/RUBBoS

And when I came to this part:

```
To build the client emulator, change into the Client directory and run make. This will create rubbos_client.jar which will be used to run the benchmark.
```

When I run `make`, I receive this error:

```
root@webserver:/home/user/RUBBoS/Client# make
/bin/javac -deprecation -classpath .:/lib/j2ee.jar:/jre/lib/rt.jar edu/rice/rubbos/client/URLGenerator.java
make: /bin/javac: Command not found
make: *** [edu/rice/rubbos/client/URLGenerator.class] Error 127
```

New error:

```
/opt/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/javac -deprecation -classpath .:/lib/j2ee.jar:/opt/jdk1.7.0_80/jre/lib/rt.jar edu/rice/rubbos/client/URLGenerator.java
make: /opt/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/javac: Command not found
make: *** [edu/rice/rubbos/client/URLGenerator.class] Error 127
```

Comment: Did you modify the Makefile? There is variable JAVAC which points to `javac` and needs to be adjusted if javac is not installed in the default location. However, in the Makefile, it defaults to `/usr/bin/javac`, not `/bin/javac`. Where is your JDK installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to your JDK installation directory.

The Makefile in the Client directory includes `../config.mk` which sets the `JAVAC` variable as

```
JAVAC = $(JAVA_HOME)/bin/javac
```

If `JAVA_HOME` is empty, you get `/bin/javac` which is what you observe.

For `bash` like shells, use something like

```
$ export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.7.0_80
$ make
```

Modify the path (`/opt/jdk1.7.0_80`)  according to where you have installed the JDK.

Note that there is also a `J2EE_HOME` environment variable which you also must set to your application server home - otherwise you will get an invalid classpath (see `/lib/j2ee.jar` in the `make` output in the question)

Comment: Where is your JDK installed? You of course need to modify the path, `/opt/jdk1.7.0_80` is an example only

Comment: This was the command: `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk`